# How to sum the output of two javascript range sliders (commission calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a commission calculator using sliders. I have two sliders that I want to be able to display the sum of. I have both the outputs, but I cannot work out how to convert that into a total.

```js
var comslider = document.getElementById("sale");
var comoutput = document.getElementById("saleprice");
comoutput.innerHTML = comslider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
comslider.oninput = function() {
  comoutput.innerHTML = this.value;
}


var slider = document.getElementById("commission_range");
var output = document.getElementById("commission");
// output += (commission / 100);
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// This is what I have tried 
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var comp = document.getElementById("commission");
var total = parseInt(salep) * parseInt(comp);
// var totalout = document.getElementById("total_commission");
// totalout.innerHTML = total.value;
document.write(total);
// total.oninput = function() {total.innerHTML = this.value;}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Final sale price of home:</p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3000000" value="500000" class="slider" id="sale">
</div>


<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Final sale price of home:</p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="3" class="slider" id="commission_range" step="0.1">
</div>


<div class="outputbox">
  <p>Final sale price of home: <span id="saleprice"></span></p>
  <p>Commission percentage: <span id="commission"></span>%</p>
  <p>Total commission: <span id="total_commission"></span></p>
</div>
```

I expect the output to multiply the `sale` value by ('commission'/100) to produce the calculated commission cost.

Comment: Make sure you correct for `console.log(0.7/0.2)` and all JavaScript Floating Point Math issues. I recommend converting Numbers to Strings and taking out the decimal place, so you can `+= '0'` in a loop. Just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that your biggest mistake was trying to parse html elements to an integer and trying to use `value` property of variable `total` which is undefined. I wrapped up the logic you wanted in the `calcTotalCommission` function with respect to your syntax choices.

```
var comslider = document.getElementById("sale");
var comoutput = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var comp = document.getElementById("commission");
var totalout = document.getElementById("total_commission");
var slider = document.getElementById("commission_range");
var output = document.getElementById("commission");

comoutput.innerHTML = comslider.value; // Display the default slider value
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
comslider.oninput = function() {
  comoutput.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the totalCommision number with current values
function calcTotalCommission(price, percentage) {
  var total = parseInt(salep.innerHTML) * (parseFloat(comp.innerHTML) / 100);
  totalout.innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Final sale price of home:</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="3000000" value="500000" class="slider" id="sale">
    </div>


    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Final sale price of home:</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="3" class="slider" id="commission_range" step="0.1">
    </div>


    <div class="outputbox">
      <p>Final sale price of home: <span id="saleprice"></span></p>
      <p>Commission percentage: <span id="commission"></span>%</p>
      <p>Total commission: <span id="total_commission"></span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the element and not the value.

```
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var comp = document.getElementById("commission");
```

And then you are parsing and adding the element, not the value.

```
var total = parseInt(salep) * parseInt(comp);
```

Use

```
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice").innerHTML;
var comp = document.getElementById("commission").innerHTML;
```